# Does $P(\exp_p(a),\exp_p(b))=0$ imply $P=0$, where $\exp_p(\cdot)$ is $p$-adic exponential?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-analysis

Classical case:

Let $\{a,b\}$ be linearly independent set over $\mathbb Q$ and $\{e^{at},e^{bt}\}$ be linearly independent set over $\mathbb Q[[t]]$. Suppose $P(x,y)$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$. Then it seems $P(e^{a},e^{b})=0$ implies $P=0$, because
if $P(x,y)=Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2 \in \mathbb Q[x,y]$. Then,
\begin{align}& P(e^{a},e^{b})=0 \\
\Rightarrow & Ae^{2a}+Be^{a+b}+Ce^{2b}=0 \\ \Rightarrow &A=B=C=0,~\text{because $a,b$ are linearly independent}  \end{align}
The same is true for any arbitrary polynomials $P(x,y) \in \mathbb Q[x,y]$, because $P(e^{a},e^{b})$ can be written as linear combinations of exponentials of the form $e^{c}$, where $c=n_1a+n_2b$, $n_1,n_2 \in \mathbb N$. But since $\{a,b\}$ is linearly independent, $P=0$.

> Does the same hold for $p$-adic exponential as well ?

$p$-adic case:

Let $\exp_p$ denotes the $p$-adic exponential function satisfying $\exp_p(x+y)=\exp_p(x) \exp_p(y)$ for $|x,y|_p<p^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}$.

Let $\{a,b\}$ be linearly independent set over $\mathbb Q$ and $\{\exp_p(at), \exp_p(bt)\}$ be linearly independent set over $\mathbb Q[[t]]$. Suppose $P(x,y)$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$. Then it seems $P(\exp_p(a), \exp_p(b))=0$ implies $P=0$, because
if $P(x,y)=Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2 \in \mathbb Q[x,y]$. Then,
\begin{align}& P(\exp_p(a), \exp_p(b))=0 \\
\Rightarrow & A\exp_p(2a)+B \exp_p(a+b)+C\exp_p(2b)=0 \end{align}
I think, as  $a,b$ are linearly independent, the $p$-adic exponential $\exp_p(2a),~\exp_p(2b)$ and $\exp_p(2(a+b))$ will not cancel, so we must have $A=B=C=0$. In other word, $P=0$. The same will be true for arbitrary polynomial.

So the answer seems to be positive, if there is no flaw in my argument.

I appreciate your comments.

Comment: I don't understand how $P(\exp(a), \exp(b))=0$ implies $P(\exp(at), \exp(bt)) =0$ in your arguments.

Comment: @AchimKrause, sorry, it was typo. see the edited question

Comment: My counterexample (see my answer) still applies

Comment: @AchimKrause, I think in your answer $9^n \neq 17^m$ doesn't imply $a,b$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ because you considered $m,n$ to be integers only. Linear independency over $\mathbb Z$ may not imply linear independency over $\mathbb Q$. Can you see the comment of ACL below the accepted answer of [this questin](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255385/algebraic-independence-of-exponential-functions) ?

Comment: If you have a linear dependency over $\mathbb{Q}$, you can clear denominators to get one with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients. I'm not sure how the answer you linked relates to what you want to do, you seem to jump back and forth between $\exp(a), \exp(b)$ being independent as elements, and $\exp(ta), \exp(tb)$ being independent as functions, which are different notions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, both the classical and $p$-adic statements are false. Let $a=\log(9)$ and $b=\log(17)$ (classical or $2$-adic log). Then they are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q} $ since otherwise we would find integers $n, m$ with $9^n=17^m$. But $P(\exp(a), \exp(b))=0$ for the nontrivial polynomial $P(x, y) = 17x-9y$.
(Note that the power series $\exp(at), \exp(bt)$ are still linearly independent as asked in the question.)